# Can you enter and exit Canada with an expired US passport?

Tags: canada, passports, us-citizens

My 18 year old daughter US passport has expired we are going to Canada in two weeks. Can she get into and out of Canada with an expired US passport.

Comment: I just went on a roadtrip to Toronto with a friend who had an expired passport, and we had no issues whatsoever.  See: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/111163/42190

Answer (score 3):

You can find full details on what documentation is required to travel been the US and Canada at [www.getyouhome.gov](http://www.getyouhome.gov/)

But in short, if you are flying then the answer will be No.  If you are entering by road/sea the answer is still most likely no, unless she happens to have an Enhanced Drivers License.

Comment: Surely she'd be able to get in; if it's clear that she's a US citizen, they can't keep her out.  I think they would fine her or charge a hefty fee, however, if she did not have a valid document from the list.

Comment: @phoog RE: “if it's clear that she's a US citizen, they can't keep her out” – Your comment is entirely incorrect. Canada controls her own border. **US citizens have no intrinsic right to enter** any foreign country, and certainly not Canada. Canada has every right to pick and choose whom they permit to enter by whatever criteria their government determines (excepting a few special obligations by treaty and international law).

Comment: @BasilBourque I am quite certain that I was speaking about her return to the US, though I see now that I may have misunderstood. I was probably misled by the link ... getyouhome.gov is about people returning to the US.

Comment: @phoog What return to the US were you talking about? She can’t get into Canada, so she won’t be returning to the US.

Comment: @MikeScott Canada does not require US citizens to have a passport.