# Got a plane ticket but no passport

Tags: air-travel, passports, us-citizens

So I did some math and ordered my plane ticket while my passport was still processing.  Now it turns out that my passport won't be here in time for my travel date. Is there anything else I can provide at the airport to show I have a verified passport or something to get through?

Comment: Are you from the USA and are to traveling internationally to a place that is not Canada, Mexico, or the Virgin Islands.

Comment: Yes im traveling to Poland for 3 months to see my gf

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, you'll need a (real, physical) passport to enter Poland, no ifs or buts

You can request an expedited passport by mail for an extra fee, or there are 28 passport centers across the USA where you can get same day processing for an even bigger fee. Since you've already mailed in an application, you may want to call them on the phone (1-877-487-2778  TDD/TTY: 1-888-874-7793) to see if you can expedite your current application.

More info can be found on the [State Department website](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/services/expedited.html)

The update to this T.SE question [notes the poster's experience with third-party expediter service](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19036/can-you-travel-to-canada-by-road-with-an-expired-us-passport?rq=1).

Comment: Just an idea (worked for me, but I'm not in the USA): Ask the office where you applied for your passport whether they can turn your application into an express. Then you don't have to pay the passport fee twice, only add the express fee.

Comment: I upgraded an application to express once, and since the passports _should_ have already arrived according to the usual schedule for routine renewals, they waived the fee. I wouldn't count on that though.

Answer (score 6):

The US Department of State website [says](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/information/processing-times.html):

> If you are traveling within 2 weeks or need a passport for a foreign
>   visa within 4 weeks and: Have
>   already applied, please contact our National Passport Information
>   Center (1-877-487-2778) to speak with a Customer Service Representative when you are 7
>   days out from your travel date.

So if you're within a week, you may be able to pay to have the passport mailed to you more quickly for instance.